# Venn Diagram for abritrary set identity

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory

I'm having a bit of a problem with producing a venn diagram of this relationship. I have three circles:  $U$, $V$, $W$. The identity I have to create is:

$$( U \setminus V ) \setminus W = U \setminus ( V \cup W)$$

I thought the shaded region would be the parts that are only in $U$, but that really seems like a wrong answer. Can someone help me out? Cheers

Comment: I belive that you are correct. Each side represents the elements that are in $U$, but not in either $V$ or $W$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it's not wrong.  Your *original* instinct was correct.

The definition of *set difference* is everything in the first set that is not in the second.

Thus the set of elements in U that are not in V, that are also not in W, is equivalent to the set of elements in U that are not in V or W.

$\begin{align}
(U\setminus V)\setminus W & = (U\cap V^c) \cap W^c & \text{by } A\setminus B = A\cap B^c
\\[1ex] & = U\cap (V^c\cap W^c) & \text {by associativity}
\\[1ex] & = U\cap(V\cup W)^c & \text{by DeMorgan's Rule}
\\[1ex] & = U\setminus (V\cup W) & \text{by }A\cap B^c = A\setminus B
\\[3ex]
\therefore (U\setminus V)\setminus W & = U\setminus (V \cup W)
\end{align}$

---

On the Venn diagram, you have three overlapping circles, U,V,W.  Show how excluding the to overlap of U with V, and the the overlap of the remainder with W, (the LHS) is the same as excluding from U the overlap with the union of V and W (the RHS).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Sorry for the noob question, but from when I learned DeMorgans law we didn't used advanced notation really, what does the superset c mean? Also, is this sufficient as an answer? http://screencast.com/t/RES9zjwwH

Comment: @Defait $A^c$ means the complement of $A$.  Sometimes represented as $\neg A$, $\bar A$, or $!A$.